# How to define an optional parameter in path using swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi

There is a function in my REST web service working with GET method and it has two optional parameters.

I tried to define it in Swagger but I encountered an error, **Not a valid parameter definition**, after I set the `required` as `false`.

I found out that if I set the `required` value as `true` the error will be gone. Here is a sample of my Swagger code.

```
...
paths:
  '/get/{param1}/{param2}':
    get:
      ...
      parameters:
      - name: param1
        in: path
        description: 'description regarding param1'
        required: false
        type: string
      - name: param2
        in: path
        description: 'description regarding param2'
        required: false
        type: string
```

I didn't experience this with parameters in body or the the ones in query. I think this problem is only related to parameters in path. I could not find any solution in swagger specification files either.

Is there any other way to define optional parameters in Swagger or do I have any mistake in my code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Given that path parameter must be required [according to the *OpenAPI/Swagger* spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-7), you can consider adding 2 separate endpoints with the following paths:

- `/get/{param1}/{param2}` *when param2 is provided*
- `/get/{param1}/` *when param2 is not provided*

Comment: I came here searching for a solution of a bit different problem. I get these errors very often when converting from WADL to Swagger using The API Transformer. For now I'm resolving these manually by adding two separate routes. I'm in search for a better converter that adds all the endpoints automatically instead of marking required as false and failing.

Comment: @vezenkov have you tried https://github.com/lucybot/api-spec-converter to do the conversion?

Comment: Sorry but you don't answer to the question at all. Please give a clear answer `It's not possible` if it's really not possible and give an alternative if you want.

Answer (score 31):

It it likely blowing up because you cannot have a base uri parameter optional, only query string values (in the case of a url).

For example:

- GET /products/{id}/pricing?foo=bar
- ** If foo is optional then your IN parameter needs to be "query" not "path"
- ** If {id} is optional then something is wrong.  {id} can't be optional because it is contained within the base uri.

This should work:

```
{
"in":"query",
"required":false
}
```

This should not work

```
{
"in":"path",
"required":false
}
```

change your "in" property to be "query" instead of "path" and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you will be able to have an optional parameter in the "path".  It is not a Swagger thing, but rather how the URL schema works.  If you have GET /products/{id} and you say that {id} is optional then you have completely changed the url that the resource is targeting (i.e. now GET /products).  Perhaps you could take this back to them and ask them why they want an optional parameter in the base uri.  I work with REST APIs a lot and this sounds like a case where the request/resource may need to be thought out a bit more to solve the problem.  Good luck!

Comment: Does query work if i have following endpoints:
/resource?querystring and /resource/{id} ? Can {id} be distinguished from query parameters?

Comment: Well, last part of url can be optional without blowing up anything, without this parameter you get the list, with this parameter you get a given item.
This is a problem in Swagger, not in the Web API Swagger is trying to document.

Comment: This does not works. Validation of the JSON fails.

Answer (score 8):

Sad but fact there is no official support for optional parameters still in 2020 and in 3.* specification:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/93

You can only apply some workaround mentioned in other answers (describe several endpoints for every set of parameters; convert your API to work with query-parameters instead of path-parameters).

Personally I decided to just leave everything as is, just add a parameter `description` which clearly says "This parameter is OPTIONAL!". Should be clear enough for everyone who reads the API.

Answer (score 6):

Your YAML fails because as it stated on the specification:

> Determines whether this parameter is mandatory. If the parameter is in "path", this property is required and its value MUST be true.

Source: http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject (Look in *fixed fields* table)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding 2 endpoints for the same API. like

`/get/{param1}/{param2}` and `/get/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}`

Answer (score 1):

In laravel or nelmio bundle for symfony works:

@OA\Parameter(
name="param2",
description="Param 2",
in="path",
**allowEmptyValue=true**,
example="1234",
required=false,

Im not sure if in works in yaml for swagger. But should work.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?