# How to make the input paramter option in Swagger while calling Rest Endpoint

Tags: swagger, spring-restcontroller

I already went through: [How to define an optional parameter in path using swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011192/how-to-define-an-optional-parameter-in-path-using-swagger).

I've this endpoint:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve Student Data By firstName Or lastName Or middleName",nickname = "Find Student Data")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully Retrieved Student Data"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "No data found !!!") })
@GetMapping(path = "/firstName/{firstName}/lastName/{lastName}/middleName/{middleName}")
public GetStudentDataResponse getStudentData(@PathVariable(required = false) String firstName, @PathVariable(required = false) String lastName,@PathVariable(required = false) String middleName) {
    return service.getStudentData(firstName,lastName,middleName);
}
```

When I hit the rest endpoint and pass firstName only, Swagger is complaining about required parameter. How can we disabled it ?

[image]

Note: I really don't want to create another endpoint just to create / for the sake of to make it working via swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`. Then it allows you to make the Parameters optional.