# PathVariable as optional in swagger SpringFox(3.0.0)

Tags: java, swagger-ui, openapi, springfox

I have upgraded to the latest version of `SpringFox(3.0.0)` recently.
`PathVariable` marked as `required = false` is showing as mandatory.

Below is my controller method code

```
@GetMapping(path = { "/persons", "/persons/{id} })
public List<Person> getPerson(@PathVariable(required = false) String id) {
    
}
```

I have tried adding `@ApiParam`, by default it is `false`. But still, on swagger it is showing as mandatory.

Previously with `SpringFox(2.9.0)` it was working fine, on swagger it was marked as optional

Any help in this will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: In OpenAPI, path parameters are [always required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35011192/113116). To have a path with an optional param parameter, you need to define 2 paths - with and without that parameter.

Comment: @Helen I wrote 'GetMapping(path = {"/descriptive","/{periodName}/descriptive"})' but still have same problem!

Comment: @OmidAshouri, in my case it works with your code structure. I have in my controller:
```@GetMapping(path = {"/{mailId}", ""})```

```ResponseEntity<?> getMails(@PathVariable(required = false) String mailId);```
with SpringFox 3.0.1. Then SwaggerUI shows 2 endpoints, one with PathVariable, one without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Path parameters are always required. If we are having an optional path variable then we need to define the two separate end poinds.

I have added two endpoints to solve my problem as shown below.

```
@GetMapping(path = { "/persons })
public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
    
}

@GetMapping(path = {"/persons/{id} })
public List<Person> getPersonById(@PathVariable String id) {
    
}
```