# Why are Matrix parameters always generated as required by Swagger / OpenAPI plugin?

Tags: java, maven, swagger

In our Java code, we annotate our REST endpoints with Swagger annotations to document them. However, regardless whethere a Matrix parameter is configured as required or not, it is generated in the `openapi.yaml` as `required`.

Here's the parameter in Java:

```
  @Parameter(required = false, allowEmptyValue = false)
  @MatrixParam("fristId") final Integer fristId
```

We use the Maven plugin `io.openapitools.swagger:swagger-maven-plugin:2.1.6` which generates the following:

```
      parameters:
      - name: fristId
        in: path
        required: true
        style: matrix
        schema:
          type: integer
          format: int32
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in the plugin? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because matrix parameters are URL path parameters, and path parameters [are always required](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#parameterRequired) according to the OpenAPI Specification.

To have an optional path parameter, you'll have to [define 2 paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65335044/113116) - one with and one without that parameter.

Other parameter types - query, header, cookie, and form parameters - can be either required and optional.