# springdoc-openapi-ui + swagger don't understand @PathVariable required = false flag

Tags: spring, swagger, spring-restcontroller, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I use this library for generation documentation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have this controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test{hz}")
    public String test(@PathVariable(value = "hz", required = false) String hz) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

But I get this documentation:

[image]

Why `required = false` doesn't work?

I tried this:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test{hz}")
    public String test(
            @Parameter(description = "foo", required = false)
            @PathVariable(value = "hz", required = false) String hz) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

It doesn't work too

**EDIT**: (Answer for @Helen comment) - Of course I know about this:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = {"/test", "/test{hz}"})
    public String test(
            @Parameter(description = "foo", required = false)
            @PathVariable(value = "hz", required = false) String hz) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

And I tried this:

```
@PathVariable(value = "hz", required = false) Optional<String> hz
```

It makes documentation worse. so I didn't add this code. With `{"/test", "/test{hz}"}` It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Path parameter are always required. To have an optional path parameter, you'll need to [define two paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35030135/113116) - with and without that parameter.

Comment: @ Helen I added more information to my question.

Comment: `@PathVariable` MUST have `required = true`, path parameters cannot be marked optional. You need to define 2 separate methods - one with the `hz` parameter and one without it.

Comment: @Helen it looks strange. Why do you so categorical?  Spring annotation `public @interface PathVariable` has a parameter `boolean required() default true;` and I can set `required == false` and it works in Spring. Swagger annotation `public @interface Parameter` has `boolean required() default false;` Why have to I use 2  separate methods? Spring allows me use one method `@GetMapping(value = {"/test", "/test{hz}"})`. Do you consider that library(swagger) must dictate rules?

Comment: [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#user-content-parameterrequired) states that path parameters MUST have `required: true`. They cannot be optional. Maybe @PathVariable with required=false is an option for other API description formats, but it's not compatible with OpenAPI. You need two separate methods because the method for `/test{hz}` must have a required path parameter and the method for `/test` must have no parameters.

Comment: @Helen I have known it since your first answer. I just want to say that it is uncomfortable. It is bad practice to change API signature only for OpenAPI Specification

Comment: There's an existing feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repo to add [support for optional path parameters](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/622), maybe this will be supported in the future.

Comment: Although the request is open, I think the sole purpose of having a path parameter as opposed to query parameter is the fact that it is not optional. Also, given the fact that path parameters can appear in between the path, in which case a missing value for it might lead to ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

This is conform to the OpenAPI specification.

> Each path parameter must be substituted with an actual value when the client makes an API call. In OpenAPI, a path parameter is defined using in: path. The parameter name must be the same as specified in the path. Also remember to add **required: true**, because path parameters are always required.

You can have a look at the documentation:

- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#path-parameters