# How to make non-obligatory param in swagger for .net core api method

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

I noticed, that my swagger index page, renders a mandatory field `id` although I set in the code `[HttpGet("{id?}")]`

Here is the whole method:

```
/// <summary>
///  Returns all projects
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
[ProducesDefaultResponseType]
[HttpGet("{id?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int? id)
{
    return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetProjectsQuery { Id = id }));
}
```

Where I went wrong?

Comment: Because it is in route. I think you can not nullable values in route.

Comment: But I read that it can with this question mark symbol?

Comment: How are you configuring Swagger? Do you have a screenshot of the generated spec for this method?

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011192/how-to-define-an-optional-parameter-in-path-using-swagger

Comment: You might just need to give the `id` parameter a default value (i.e. `int? id = null`). [If a route parameter is optional, you must define a default value for the method parameter.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional-uri-parameters-and-default-values)

Comment: I added nullable param but still nothing..it forces me to add id

Answer (score 0):

The questions is a little bit old here, not sure if you found the solutions yet or not
But I suggested you could make a try with the Route Attributes
You can reference the [Documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#adding-route-attributes)
Below is sample code without tested

```
/// <summary>
///  Returns all projects
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
[ProducesDefaultResponseType]
[Route("api/Get")]
[Route("api/Get/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] int? id)
{
    return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetProjectsQuery { Id = id }));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Remove the `id?` from your HttpVerb and the `FromRoute` from method signature.

```
/// <summary>
///  Returns all projects
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
[ProducesDefaultResponseType]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int? id)
{
    return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetProjectsQuery { Id = id }));
}
```

Comment: this is not a question how to do on another way. I know for that solution, but I want to have nullable param from route. thanks