# Why Optional and @PathVariable combination is not supported by Spring/java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I would like to make an api that could accept two Path variables and one of them could be optional.
In this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-optional-path-variables) they said that we can achieve this by using Optional, but this is not working.

here is my **Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/users/{dateDu}/{dateAu}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsersByDate(
        @PathVariable LocalDate dateDu,
        @PathVariable(required = false) Optional<LocalDate> dateAu,
        @org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable
    ) {
        if(dateAu.isEmpty()){
            dateAu = Optional.of(LocalDate.now()); 
        }
        Page<User> page = userRepository.getUsersByDate(dateDu, dateAu.get(), pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

in this image of swagger the two parameters are required even if the second one has `Optional`

[image]

Since I generated my spring boot app with JHipster, on postman when I don't give a the value of the Optional parameter. I got this error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="fr" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="Description for " />
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webapp" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/loading.css" />
    <!-- jhipster-needle-add-resources-to-root - JHipster will add new resources here -->
    <base href="/">
</head>

<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <p class="browserupgrade">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve
        your experience.
      </p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div id="root">
        <div class="app-loading">
            <div class="lds-pacman">
                <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="app-loading">
            <div id="jhipster-error" style="display: none">
                <!-- This content is for troubleshooting purpose and will be removed when app renders -->
                <h1>An error has occurred :-(</h1>
                <h2>Usual error causes</h2>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        You started the application from an IDE and you didn't run
                        <code style="color: red">npm start</code> or
                        <code style="color: red">npm run webapp:build</code>.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        You had a network error while running <code style="color: red">npm install</code>. If you are
                        behind a corporate proxy, it is
                        likely that this error was caused by your proxy. Have a look at the JHipster error logs, you
                        will probably have the cause of
                        the error.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        You installed a Node.js version that doesn't work with JHipster: please use an LTS (long-term
                        support) version, as it's the
                        only version we support.
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <h2>Building the client side code again</h2>
                <p>If you want to go fast, run <code style="color: red">./mvnw</code> to build and run everything.</p>
                <p>If you want to have more control, so you can debug your issue more easily, you should follow the
                    following steps:</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>Install npm dependencies with the command <code style="color: red">npm install</code></li>
                    <li>
                        Build the client with the command <code style="color: red">npm run webapp:build</code> or
                        <code style="color: red">npm start</code>
                    </li>
                    <li>Start the server with <code style="color: red">./mvnw</code> or using your IDE</li>
                </ol>

                <h2>Getting more help</h2>

                <h3>If you have a question on how to use JHipster</h3>
                <p>
                    Go to Stack Overflow with the
                    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jhipster" target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer">"jhipster"</a> tag.
                </p>

                <h3>If you have a bug or a feature request</h3>
                <p>
                    First read our
                    <a href="https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md" target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer">contributing guidelines</a>.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Then, fill a ticket on our
                    <a href="https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/new/choose" target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer">bug tracker</a>, we'll be happy to resolve your issue!
                </p>

                <h3>If you want to chat with contributors and other users</h3>
                <p>
                    Join our chat room on
                    <a href="https://gitter.im/jhipster/generator-jhipster" target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer">Gitter.im</a>. Please note
                    that this is a public chat room, and that we expect you to respect other people and write in a
                    correct English language!
                </p>
                <!-- end of troubleshooting content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <noscript>
        <h1>You must enable JavaScript to view this page.</h1>
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // show an error message if the app loading takes more than 4 sec
      window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(showError, 4000);
      };
      function showError() {
        var errorElm = document.getElementById('jhipster-error');
        if (errorElm && errorElm.style) {
          errorElm.style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    </script>
    <!-- uncomment this for adding service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
            .then(function () {
              console.log('Service Worker Registered');
            });
        });
      }
    </script>
    -->
    <!-- Google Analytics: uncomment and change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID.
    <script>
      (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
      function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
      e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
      e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
      r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
      ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
    </script>-->
    <script defer src="app/vendors.bundle.js"></script>
    <script defer src="app/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would appreciate if any one could help me to understand why this is happening and/or how I could solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not have 2 methods, one with 2 arguments, one with 1 argument, and then call the 1st one from the 2nd one?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems to me like it's not elegant to use 2 methods. And I can't understand why they give the possibility to combine the Optional and PathVariable and in the same time they're not working together

Comment: Since I am not attempting to solve the problem, but instead offering a work-around, I used a comment instead of an actual answer. I agree it is not especially elegant - but it *would* work.

Comment: if there is not a proper solution I'll opt for this work-around. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a composite question. I found some issues in your question.

First, you should change your path to

```java
@GetMapping(value = {"/users/{dateDu}", "/users/{dateDu}/{dateAu}"})
```

Otherwise you will get 404 error if you don't provide `dateAu` in your request.

---

Second, you should add `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)` to your parameters to tell Spring how to convert String to LocalDate. Otherwise you will get a `Bad Request` with error message.

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'

You didn't notice this issue because Swagger have already handled it for you, I guess.

I try to fix your code:

```java
@GetMapping(value = {"/users/{dateDu}", "/users/{dateDu}/{dateAu}"})
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsersByDate(
    @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate dateDu,
    @PathVariable(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Optional<LocalDate> dateAu,
    @org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable) {
    if (dateAu.isEmpty()) {
        dateAu = Optional.of(LocalDate.now()); 
    }
    Page<User> page = userRepository.getUsersByDate(dateDu, dateAu.get(), pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil
        .generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
}
```

I think it should be work if you use postman to test.

---

Third, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35030135/5485454), all of `@PathVariable` **MUST be required** in Swagger. It means your question is nothing to do with combination of `@PathVariable` and `Optional` in Java. It's a spec/limitation of Swagger. Thus, if you really want to use Swagger to test your API, you have 2 choices:

1. Split it to 2 endpoints, as @tucuxi said.
2. Use QueryString style instead.

---

Last, it seems like you probably don't need an `Optional`. `Optional` is designed to be used as a return type in most case. But this is a controversial design issue. So, if you really want to use `Optional`, you can follow the best practice described by [this excellent article](https://ducmanhphan.github.io/2019-12-06-Best-practice-for-Optional-in-Java/#using-ifpresent()-or-ifPresentOrElse()-methods)

Comment: Thank you for the effort. But unfortunately it's not solving the problem; the two parameters still required

Comment: @hakimamaarouf Could you provide error log or stacktrace?

Comment: The designers can say all they want that `Optional` should have been used only as a return type, but in real code it's also used as an input type, and especially as a field type on parameter objects. In a case like Spring controllers, it's perfectly clear.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-   `Optional` in `@PathVariable(required = false) Optional<LocalDate>` is a duplicated representation IMO. And then using `ifPresent()`, `get()`  is not better than a  plain null check.

Comment: If the parameter is necessary, why would it be of the 'Optional' type?
Sorry for my ignorance, but I don't see any sense, if possible, explain..

Comment: @Kai-ShengYang I don't have an error log or stacktrace, in swagger when I try to execute the method the input become colored in red and the methed doesn't get executed. I tried also in Postman and it gives me the HTML  I added above which contains some errors (I guess this page generated by JHipster)

Comment: @hakimamaarouf if you provide all parameters in swagger or postman, does your api work correctly?

Comment: @Kai-ShengYang Definitely agreed about the style concerns, simply that `Optional` as a parameter is fine.

Comment: @RafaeldaSilva The alternative (with `required = false`) is a null value.

Comment: @Kai-ShengYang yes it works fine with all params

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding the 2 paths to the @GetMapping?

@GetMapping("/users/{dateDu}", "/users/{dateDu}/{dateAu}")

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that solves your problem, but you should probably remove the false flag in the annotation of your param:
`@PathVariable Optional<LocalDate> dateAu` and add both paths: `@GetMapping(value = {"/users/{dateDu}", "/users/{dateDu}/{dateAu}"})`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to give my param in the path so I can't remove @PathVariable. I tried to remove just the false flag but it keep showing the two params as required